# It seems to be no change in docs, but why does width give different image scale between Bootstrap 4 and 5?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

My image is in a grid column.
When I use Bootstrap 4 the`.title-image { width: 60%;}` works as expected.

However when switching to BS 5 it just pops out and enlarged. It's like the `width` is set to correspond with the body width, not with the image column container anymore.

The docs of Bootstrap 4.5 and 5 indicate that they both treat image with `.img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto;)`

source:

v5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/images/

v4.5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/

So the same specs, but why does `width: 60%;` behave differently?

CSS

```
.title-image {
  width: 60%;  /* this has different image display
                  between Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5. Why? */
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 23%;
}

#features {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 7% 15%;
  position: relative;
}

/* below is just decoration */
#title {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

p {
  color: #8f8f8f;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15%;
}

.navbar {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.download-button {
  margin: 3%;
}
```

HTML

```
 <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Nav Bar -->

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/yFBgCTG/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
      
  </div>
</section>

  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="grid-align-center col-lg-4">
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-align-center col-lg-4">
          <i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i>
          <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
          <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-align-center col-lg-4">
          <i class="fas fa-heart grid-align-center"></i>
          <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
          <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

For your reference (you can change the Bootstrap fw between 4 and 5 in the codeply setting icon): https://www.codeply.com/p/0PxYAi3JWt

Comment: Please add your code directly on the question

Comment: @YLR hi, thanks I've edited my question (add codes and some more clarification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is between Bootstrap4 and Bootstrap5 `.col-lg-6` -- `position: relative` was removed for all column selectors in Bootstrap5 while Bootstrap4 did use it.

Your css `.title-image { position: absolute; }` relies on the parent element having `position: relative` to work as intended. I'm not certain why the change was made between 4 and 5, but you can update the parent div to `col-lg-6 position-relative` to address.

Comment: thank you! that's really something I've missed when I read the docs.

Comment: I just searched through the docs since I'm not familiar with 5 yet but couldn't find it on a quick read and ctrl+f.